# How to set date type in postgres to the DD/MM/YYYY Format

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I am creating some tables in Postgres with date columns such as date of birth. When I enter the value as 19-09-2021 for example, I got the error `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "19-09-2021"`

Which suggest that the default format is YYYY/MM/DD. How can I change the format to DD/MM/YYYY to accept similar values.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 and 9.4 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in Postgres (or really in *any* SQL database) do not have an internal format, but rather are stored as binary.  You should be using valid date literals in your SQL queries against bona fide date columns, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date_col = '2021-09-19'::date;
```

If you want to *view* your date column a certain way, then use Postgres' `TO_CHAR` function:

```sql
SELECT date_col, TO_CHAR(date_col, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date_col_text
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Will it be correct to just store the date type as DATE in the table? i.e. ```create table profiles (
  birth_date Date);```

Comment: @Wacademy Yes, barring any other issues you haven't mentioned, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should to check [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html) setting:

```
postgres=# show datestyle ;
┌───────────┐
│ DateStyle │
╞═══════════╡
│ ISO, DMY  │
└───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Although I use German style in life, I agree with opinion so for input, then best is ISO style, and this style should be preferred, because it is not ambiguous, and Postgres accept this style (and almost all other databases) with any setting:

```
postgres=# set datestyle to US;
SET
postgres=# select '20210817'::date;
┌────────────┐
│    date    │
╞════════════╡
│ 2021-08-17 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select '17-08-2021'::date;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "17-08-2021"
LINE 1: select '17-08-2021'::date;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
postgres=# set datestyle to german ;
SET
postgres=# select '17-08-2021'::date;
┌────────────┐
│    date    │
╞════════════╡
│ 17.08.2021 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select '17/08/2021'::date;
┌────────────┐
│    date    │
╞════════════╡
│ 17.08.2021 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `SQL Shell`.

You can check your date style from here `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\Your Server(like mine 13)\data`

after that open this file ->  `postgresql.conf`

Find datestyle option, look like this -> `datestyle = 'iso, mdy'`

You can change here default Date Style Setting according your Date Style or you also use by default date style.

Comment: `show datestyle;` is independent of the SQL client used. There is no real need to consult the config file for this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know but if you want to use according your date style then you have to do it. other wise go with default use.

Comment: I dont think this will be ideal